# gem 'timezone' on Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, geonames

I have made an account on GeoNames enabled free webservrices to use gem 'timezone' (about a day ago). When I go to `http://www.geonames.org/enablefreewebservice` it says

```
 The account my_user_name has been successfully enabled to use the free webservices.
```

When I put the following in the address bar and click enter it works, too

```
http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes?lat=47&lng=9&username=my_user_name
```

However when I run the following in my Rail4 application console

```
Timezone::Configure.begin do |c|
  c.username = 'xxxx'
end
timezone = Timezone::Zone.new :latlon => [-34.92771808058, 138.477041423321]
```

I get the error message:

```
 Timezone::Error::NilZone: No zone was found. Please specify a zone.
```

This is my first time using GeoNames so I'm not over the limit. How may I go about fixing this? One thing I noticed, `require 'timezone'` returns false in console.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried the same with rails 3 which worked and returned me "Australia/Adelaide" zone.

Comment: Looks like you have configured wrong username. When I change username to invalid, it gives the same error.

Comment: i have configured right username. But it gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your username config is probably undefined. Open the console up and check

```
Timezone::Configure.username
```

If it's `nil`, you've found your problem!

Try placing your config code inside an initializer, instead of `application.rb`. Try creating the file `config/initializers/timezone.rb` and place the code there.

```
Timezone::Configure.begin do |c|
  c.username = 'xxxx'
end
```

Fire up the console after that and check the username again. If it's now defined your request should now work!